# Counting array values returns an extra result

Tags: php, arrays, count

I am currently working on a messaging system for my website that allows people to message up to 9 other people, (10 including author). I have a table on my database called 'conversations' with the following fields:

- convo_id
- author
- recipient_1
- recipient_2
- recipient_3
- recipient_4
- recipient_5
- recipient_6
- recipient_7
- recipient_8
- recipient_9
- title
- timestamp

I then have a table called 'private_messages' with these fields:

- message_id
- convo_id
- author
- timestamp
- message

So all the participants in the conversation are stored in the conversations table, and the actual messages stored on the p_m table.

I am using a single entry field on the form for the recipients, with names separated by a comma, and then have the following code on the other side of the submit:

```
$recipients = explode(",", $_POST['recipient']);
$duplicate = array($recipients[0],$recipients[1],$recipients[2],$recipients[3],$recipients[4],$recipients[5],$recipients[6],$recipients[7],$recipients[8],$recipients[9],$recipients[10]);
$unique = array_values(array_unique($duplicate));
$result = count($unique);
echo "$result<br>";
```

The issue that I'm having, is that when I echo $result, I am getting one extra on the count. If I leave the field blank, it correctly says 0, but any entry and it returns 2, which is then giving me an anomaly further down the validation.

I am completely stumped, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried error_log'ing the $_POST['recipient']?  Maybe you're adding the author to the recipient list.

Comment: Yes, $_POST['recipient'] is only returning the entered values.

Comment: Hmm you add 11 Recipients to the array... index 0 to 10. Why are you even doing the manual array stuff?

Comment: If there is only 1 recipient, what values are in the rest of the recipients array?  What does $_POST['recipient'] look like (does it have a bunch of commas with no text between it)?  I bet your unique array is the actual recipients and an empty entry.

Comment: This is just a past-time, nothing professional. I'm only self taught, so I'm not too fussed about doing things the easiest way, as-long as it works in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is your $duplicate step

```
// assuming $_POST['recipient'] = bob,fred

$recipients = explode(",", $_POST['recipient']);
// $recipients is array ['bob','fred']
$duplicate = array($recipients[0],$recipients[1],$recipients[2],$recipients[3],$recipients[4],$recipients[5],$recipients[6],$recipients[7],$recipients[8],$recipients[9],$recipients[10]);
// $duplicate is ['bob','fred',null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
$unique = array_values(array_unique($duplicate));
// $unique is ['bob','fred',null]
$result = count($unique);
//$result = 3
echo "$result<br>";
```

Intead do:

```
// assuming $_POST['recipient'] = bob,fred

$recipients = explode(",", $_POST['recipient']);
// $recipients is array ['bob','fred']
$unique = array_values(array_unique($recipients));
// $unique is ['bob','fred']
$result = count($unique);
//$result = 2
echo "$result<br>";
```

A codepad illustrating the problem: http://codepad.org/YZSvieEr